# cron service is running but not executing cron jobs in centos

Tags: tomcat, cron, centos, logrotate, catalina

I have created a policy to rotate catalina.out of tomcat, my cron service is running and I can even check the log to verify the jobs but I am not getting the desired output. Here is my code

/etc/logrotate.d/tomcat

```
/opt/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out {
    copytruncate
    rotate 7
    compress
    missingok
    size 1k
 }
```

/etc/crontab

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/

# For details see man 4 crontabs

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name command to be executed
  01 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly
  02 4 * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.daily
  22 4 * * 0 root run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
  42 4 1 * * root run-parts /etc/cron.monthly
  * * * * * root /usr/sbin/logrotate -v /etc/logrotate.conf
  * * * * * root env > /opt/env.output
```

/var/log/cron

```
Apr 24 14:49:01 staging2 CROND[30862]: (root) MAIL (mailed 5331 bytes of output but got status 0x004b#012)
Apr 24 14:50:01 staging2 CROND[30903]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Apr 24 14:50:01 staging2 CROND[30902]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/logrotate -v /etc/logrotate.conf)
Apr 24 14:50:01 staging2 CROND[30901]: (root) CMD (env > /opt/env.output)
Apr 24 14:50:01 staging2 CROND[30893]: (root) MAIL (mailed 5376 bytes of output but got status 0x004b#012)
Apr 24 14:51:01 staging2 CROND[30938]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/logrotate -v /etc/logrotate.conf)
Apr 24 14:51:01 staging2 CROND[30937]: (root) CMD (env > /opt/env.output)
Apr 24 14:51:01 staging2 CROND[30932]: (root) MAIL (mailed 5331 bytes of output but got status 0x004b#012)
Apr 24 14:52:01 staging2 CROND[30975]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/logrotate -v /etc/logrotate.conf)
Apr 24 14:52:01 staging2 CROND[30976]: (root) CMD (env > /opt/env.output)
Apr 24 14:52:01 staging2 CROND[30970]: (root) MAIL (mailed 5331 bytes of output but got status 0x004b#012)
```

I can clearly see the job is executed every minute and it should rotate catalina file but it is not doing that, if I run the command `/usr/sbin/logrotate -v /etc/logrotate.conf` manually it does the job.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. Everything was fine but u need to disable the SELinux

```
setenforce 0
```

Comment: While this may work, SELinux is there for a reason. You should identify what caused it and configure SELinux properly.